# Shell script in pipeline fails with ERROR: script returned exit code 1

Tags: linux, shell, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I've a following shell script which needs to be executed through Jenkins pipeline  -

```
sh '''cd ''' + env.WORKSPACE + '''/MountPoint/
 find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type f -printf '%f\\n' | grep \'^APP.*zip$\''''
```

When run pipeline with this, it fails with - `ERROR: script returned exit code 1`. Apart from this, no more error details provided hence no clarification about failure.

However if I execute above commands with evaluation of variables on machine, those succeed.

Could you please help to understand what is causing above shell script to fail?

Comment: You've escaped the quotes in the grep command. Should you not be escaping the quotes for printf also?

Comment: Escaping with printf also causing same issue.